# Elementary Geometry problem - Proving the angles $A'B'C'$ and $\beta$ are the same

Tags: geometry, triangles, circles, plane-geometry, tangent-line

[image]

In the above picture, the line t is tangent to the circle at $C'$. How do I prove the angle $A'B'C'$ is equal to the angle $\beta$?

I tried to do a lot of things, like tracing parallels and perpendiculars through points and using theorems of angles to use similarity of triangles or using the outer angle theorem... nothing worked.

Thanks.

Comment: This is the alternate segment theorem, see for example [this link](https://www.storyofmathematics.com/alternate-segment-theorem).

Comment: https://geometryhelp.net/tangent-chord-theorem/

Comment: http://www.timdevereux.co.uk/maths/geompages/proof7.php

Answer (score 0):

They both intercept the same arc.  They are essentially inscribed angles whose measure is one-half the intercepted arc.

Comment: The angle marked $\beta$ is not an inscribed angle.  The fact that an angle formed by a tangent and a chord has the same measure as an inscribed angle that subtends the chord is something that you need to prove (and is, in fact, what the OP is trying to find a proof for).

Comment: @MatthewDaly Although you are technically right, it is interesting to consider the following: Let $P$ be a point on the minor arc $\overset{\mmlToken{mo}{⏜}}{A'C'\,}$. Clearly, $ \measuredangle A'C'P<\measuredangle A'B'C'$ when $P$ is between $A'$ and $C'$. However, when we start moving $P$ clockwise, it will eventually coincide with $C'$, leading to an inscribed angle"ish" configuration which intuitively shows why the angles are congruent :)